# Scope of "pezzo" when it means "musical composition"

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

I have read the following sentence in an Italian learning tool:

> Suoneremo quattro o cinque pezzi.

It is clear to me that "pezzo" here means "musical composition" (part of meaning 3b in http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pezzo/ ). I think that word with that meaning is usually used only in the scope of opera, musical shows and orchestra. It also seems to me that it is a bit formal and usually it would not be used in an informal talk amoung young friends, e.g., about pop music (e.g., "Adoro il nuovo pezzo di Shakira"). Is that true?

Comment: For completeness, *pezzo* is also used in journalism, where it means *articolo*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pezzo](https://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=pezzo) (musicale) is used both in formal and colloquial contexts:

Da Garzanti:

> 5. passo, brano di un’opera musicale o letteraria; anche, breve opera indipendente: *suonare un pezzo al pianoforte; ascoltare un pezzo della «Traviata»; recitare un pezzo dell’«Amleto»*
>
>    ***canzone, brano musicale:*** *un pezzo di Fabrizio De Andrè*

Da 105.net, [*Ecco il nuovo singolo di J-Ax*](https://www.105.net/news/music-biz/251749/ecco-il-nuovo-singolo-di-j-ax.html):

> «*Ho voluto scrivere un pezzo per le persone che vivono il dramma di voler creare una nuova vita, senza riuscirci*», ha spiegato J-Ax descrivendo questo suo nuovo brano.

Da Billboard.it, [*Enrico Nigiotti: «Dopo X Factor ho scritto un pezzo per la Pausini»*](https://www.billboard.it/musica/italiana/enrico-nigiotti-intervista-pausini/2018/03/195481/):

> Quest’anno ho un lavoro, faccio il cantautore, ho fatto un disco di platino, sono andato a Sanremo come ospite e *ho scritto un pezzo per la Pausini.*  È stato un anno devastante a livello di emozioni.

Comment: From the examples of Garzanti and Treccani, it does not seem to me that "pezzo" would be used outside the scope of erudite/classical music; for instance, in the example at the end of my question.

Comment: @Alan Evangelista - please see the example about De André.

Comment: Gio, Alan: all lies in whether one feels that some kind of border passes between De André and Shakira or not...

Comment: @DaG - un “pezzo” in senso musicale è comunemente usato per riferirsi ad una canzone... di Shakira, Beyoncé, Madonna, Lucio Battisti o chi vuoi tu. Il termine non è confinato alla musica classica od operistica.

Comment: Scusa se mi sono espresso in maniera poco chiara, Gio, non ponevo in discussione il significato di “pezzo”. Ero solo divertito dal fatto che, a quel che pare,  Alan pone De André tra la musica “erudite/classic” e tu no. (Non sto prendendo posizione.)